# What is the New Zealand white sponge cake, is it a white cake here in the U.S?

Tags: cake

My friend is from New Zealand and us asking for a white sponge cake. Is that the same as a white cake in the U.S.? or does she really mean sponge cake?

Answer (score 2):

The New Zealand Edmonds cook book has a sponge cake recipe something like this. It's the only cook book we are allowed to use :-)

**Ingredients**

- 3 eggs, separated
- 3/4 cup caster sugar
- 3/4 cup Edmonds Fielder's cornflour
- 1 tablespoon Edmonds plain baking flour
- 1 teaspoon Edmonds baking powder
- 2 teaspoons golden syrup
- 1 tablespoon boiling water

**Method**

- Beat egg whites until stiff
- Beat in sugar then yolks
- Sift cornflour, flour and baking powder into egg mixture
- Add golden syrup dissolved in boiling water and mix gently with a metal spoon
- Pour into two greased and lined 20 cm sandwich tins
- Bake at 190°C for 20 minutes or until cake springs back when lightly touched
- Leave in tin for 5 minutes before turning out onto a cooling rack

Comment: Is the cake white or yellow? 3 yolks should taint it, I think.

Comment: And what does "cornflour" mean in new Zealand, rough ground corn, or corn starch?

Comment: Cornflour = cornstarch in the UK, Australia and NZ

Comment: @Mien, in general NZ eggs are not very yellow, or very large

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Yes, corn starch from corn flour- http://www.edmondscooking.co.nz/baking-ingredients/fielders-cornflour-300g